# Как узнать что есть новый платеж в Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, платежи, crm

Есть сайт на WordPress/Woocommerce. Стоит задача отправить данные об успешном платеже на CRM.
Вариант с succes_url не работает потому-что на установленных платежных систем нет такой функций.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте хук [woocommerce_payment_complete](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/woocommerce_payment_complete)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
}
```